# Where does content written to STDERR in PHP go?

Tags: php, error-handling, stderr

I understand that if the `error_log` configuration directive is not set, then errors are sent to the SAPI error logger. For example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in CLI.

So if I run a script from the command line, errors display directly (unless redirected). If I run a script from cron, errors are emailed to the cron job owner. So what happens if I pipe email to a script?

I'm just starting out writing a script to handle bounce messages. I've read that if the script outputs anything, it will bounce back to the sender. I wasn't sure if this applied to all output or just STDOUT. Or does STDERR equal STDOUT in CLI?

If I set `error_log` configuration directive to a file, can I then use `trigger_error` and `error_log` functions to safely output error messages without sending a bounce to the sender?

Since the script is processing bounces, I really want to avoid bouncing back to sender. I imagine that could cause an infinite loop. And since the error log is in another directory and the path is set in an include file, there's a remote chance something could go wrong before I can set the configuration directive. Would it be a good idea to use `ini_set('error_log', 'syslog')` at the very top of the script and then change it to my file as soon as I can?

Comment: What do you mean by "piping an email to a script" ?

Comment: Sending incoming emails (for a particular address) to a script with `| /path/to/php /path/to/script`. The script would read STDIN to get the incoming email.

Comment: I suppose you will use a custom POP client that echoes the contents of your mail box to `stdout`?

Comment: The message won't go to a mailbox because it was piped to the script by qmail. There is no mailbox. The address is an alias. The script will parse the email for some info and store some stuff to a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using CLI, both `stdout` and `stderr` go to the same place. For cron, output is emailed to the cron job owner. For command line, output is sent to the terminal. When passing the output of one program to another (via pipes), output is returned to the first program. What it does with it will depend on the program.

The simplest way to specify where errors go when using CLI is to specify it on the command line. So if piping email to a script, you could use the following:

```
| /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/script.php 2> /path/to/log/error.log
```

The number `2` is the file handle for `stderr` and the `>` redirects it to the specified file.

### PHP Configuration Directives

As for the different PHP configuration directives, they do behave differently for CLI. Apparently, there is a bug on some versions/systems where the error is not written to the log regardless of config settings.

Here are the results of testing with CLI on my system (PHP 5.3 on Centos 6):

- If `log_errors` is *on*, setting `display_errors` to *0* will not stop errors from displaying. Errors go to same place as `stdout`, unless redirected on the command line.
- If `log_errors` is *off* and `display_errors` is *off*, no errors are reported at all.
- If `log_errors` is *on* and `error_log` is set to a file (with proper permissions), then errors go to that file.
- If `log_errors` is *on* and `error_log` is set to *'syslog'*, then errors go to /var/log/messages.
- If `log_errors` is *on* and `display_errors` is *on*, two error messages are outputted: one with 'PHP' prefix and one without.
- The only difference I could see between setting `display_errors` to *1* and setting it to *'stderr'* is that the former printed an extra line break.

Note that I only tested the different configuration directives at the command line, not cron or piped to another program. I imagine that the results would be the same since they are all CLI. The only difference is where `stdout` goes.

### Alternative

Rather than worrying about what output might get returned to sender, you could allow the messages to go to a mailbox. Then use the PHP [imap](http://www.php.net/ref.imap.php) functions to read the mail. The PHP script could be run as a cron job and then any error messages would go to the cron job owner.